# Rename Linux home folder structure to system language

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xdg

I have installed the Ubuntu distro first in Portuguese.

Then, I decided I wanted the English language. I would like that the default folders like "Desktop" and "Documents" were renamed to this names, instead of staying in their Portuguese equivalent.

I can not guarantee this, but I am almost certain I did successfully convert the folder names from Portuguese to English on a previous install when I decided to change the language. So, I suppose this is possible.

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 4):

The names of these directories are in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. The file is read by the X session startup scripts.

I don't know offhand how to tell a running desktop environment that the desired names have changed. You could edit the file, rename the directories, and immediately log out and back in.

Answer (score 1):

Arch + Gnome user here. Had exactly this kind of trouble where the `/home/$USER/*` dirs were created in English, and I desperately needed them in Russian for my sister.

I manually echoed the ru_RU locale into the `~/.config/user-dirs.locale` thingy, relogged, nothing. Cleared the `user-dirs.dirs` file, still nothing. I just gave up and manually punched in the folder names. Turns out you could assign them as you wish, run `xdg-user-dirs-update` or `xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update` and bam! no relogin needed. I still had to do it to clear the stuck DING extension though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Editing the file Gilles already pointed to could be done from a text session. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open `tty2`, log in, and then kill X11. After that it's a simple

```
$ nano ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

And then something like `startx`, depending on the WM you use, to start your WM again.

(I do not know whether Gilles' solution works, this is just a slightly more elaborate explanation of the 'how'.)